# REST endpoint works when directly accessed, but not when accessed via WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

**Note: *The following is an edit/revision to a similar post/question, in an attempt to better identify my issue/question, and to provide better code samples demonstrating my issue.***

**Add Note: *Code example has been revised to include working code.***

I have two endpoints in two routers in the same spring reactive application. The first (*/v2/DemoPOJO*) appears to work correctly. The second (*/v2/DemoClient/DemoPOJO*), which uses WebClient to delegate to */v2/DemoPOJO* appears to "do nothing" (although the logged output shows that *DemoClientHandler.add()* and *DemoClient.add()* are being invoked).

When I do a POST request to the */v2/DemoPOJO* endpoint, the *doFirst()*, *doOnSuccess()*, and *doFinally()* are invoked and output the appropriate text (in "real life", a row is added to the repository).

When I do a POST request to the */v2/DemoClient/DemoPOJO* endpoint, it returns a 200 OK status, but none of the expected text is output (in "real life", nothing gets added to the repository).

The following files support the */v2/DemoPOJO* endpoint...

Router class implementation for DemoPOJO...

```
@Configuration
public class DemoPOJORouter {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoPOJORouter.class);

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> demoPOJORoute(DemoPOJOHandler requestHandler) {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJORouter.demoPOJORoute( DemoPOJOHandler )");
        return nest(path("/v2"),
                nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON),
                        RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.POST("/DemoPOJO"), requestHandler::add)));
    }
}
```

Handler class implementation for DemoPOJO...

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJOHandler {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoPOJOHandler.class);

    public Mono<ServerResponse> add(ServerRequest request) {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJOHandler.add( ServerRequest )");

        return request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doFirst(() -> System.out.println("-> doFirst()."))
                                                 .doOnSuccess(demoPOJO -> System.out.println("Received >> " + demoPOJO.toString()))
                                                     .then(ServerResponse.accepted().build())
                                                 .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("-> doOnError()"))
                                                 .doFinally(demoPOJO -> System.out.println("-> doFinally()"));
    }
}
```

*DemoPOJO* implementationj...

```
public class DemoPOJO {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoPOJO.class);

    public static final String DEF_NAME  = "DEFAULT NAME";
    public static final int    DEF_VALUE = 99;

    private int    id;
    private String name;
    private int    value;

    public DemoPOJO(@JsonProperty("id") int id, @JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("value") int value) {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJO.DemoPOJO( {}, {}, {} )", id, name, value);
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    /*
     * setters and getters go here
     */

    public String toString() {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJO.toString()");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append(id);
        builder.append(" :: ");
        builder.append(name);
        builder.append(" :: ");
        builder.append(value);
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

The following files support the */v2/DemoClient/DemoPOJO* endpoint...

Router implementation for DemoClient...

```
@Configuration
public class DemoClientRouter {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoClientRouter.class);

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> clientRoutes(DemoClientHandler requestHandler) {
        logger.debug("DemoClientRouter.route( DemoClientHandler )");
        return nest(path("/v2/DemoClient"),
                nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON),
                        RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.POST("/DemoPOJO"), requestHandler::add)));
    }
}
```

Handler implementation for DemoClient...

```
@Component
public class DemoClientHandler {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(mil.navy.demo.demopojo.DemoPOJOHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    DemoClient demoClient;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> add(ServerRequest request) {
        logger.debug("DemoClientOHandler.add( ServerRequest )");

        // THIS CODE
        return request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).flatMap(demoPOJO -> demoClient.add(demoPOJO))
                                                 .then(ServerResponse.accepted().build());

        // REPLACES THIS CODE
        /*
           return request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doOnSuccess( demoPOJO -> demoClient.add(demoPOJO))
                                                     .then(ServerResponse.ok().build())
                                                 .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.badRequest().build());
         */
    }
}
```

WebClient implementation for DemoClient...

```
@Component
public class DemoClient {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoClient.class);

    private final WebClient client;

    public DemoClient() {
        client = WebClient.create();
    }

    public Mono<Boolean> add(DemoPOJO demoPOJO) {
        logger.debug("DemoClient.add( DemoPOJO )");

        logger.debug("DemoClient.add() >> DemoPOJO -> {}", demoPOJO.toString());
        return client.post().uri("http://localhost:8080/v2/DemoPOJO")
                            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .syncBody(demoPOJO)
                            .exchange()
                            .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(Boolean.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions. Edit your original question to include all the details.

Comment: This is a bit of a paradox. The recommendation to edit the original question conflicts with the recommendation on the original question to not edit the question and invalidate the existing answer.
This is why I flagged the original question for deletion, because I did a sufficiently horrid job on the original that "saving" it resulted in editing to the point that the response didn't make sense. Which then led me to the duplicate question. <sigh> It all went wrong at "go".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is where i guess your problem is.

```
return request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class)
    .doOnSuccess( demoPOJO -> demoClient.add(demoPOJO))
```

`doOnSuccess` takes a consumer, a consumer returns `void` **not** `Mono<Void>`.

Here is the verbose usage of a `Consumer`.

```
Mono.just("hello")
    .doOnSuccess(new Consumer<String>() {

        @Override
        public void accept(String s) {

            // See here, it returns void

        }
    });
```

Lets look at some examples:

```
Mono<String> helloWorld = Mono.just("Hello")
    .doOnSuccess(string -> {
        // This will never be executed because 
        // it is just declared and never subscribed to
        Mono.just(string + " world");
    });

helloWorld.doOnSuccess(string -> {
        // This will print out Hello
        System.out.println(string);
    });

 Mono<String> hello = Mono.just("Hello")
        .doOnSuccess(string -> {
        // This will print out Hello World
        System.out.println(string + " World");
    });

 // hello hasn't been changed     
 hello.map(string -> {
        // This will also print out Hello World
        System.out.println(string + " World");
    });

 // This prints hello world to after we mapped it
 Mono<String> helloworld = Mono.just("hello")
     .map(s -> s + " World")
     .doOnSuccess(System.out::println);

 // Now this is what you are essentially doing
 // See how this is wrong?
 Mono<DemoPOJO> demoPOJO = request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class)
    .doOnSuccess( demoPOJO -> Mono.empty() );
```

you are calling `demoClient#add` that returns a `Mono<Void>` here you are breaking the chain because nothing is chained onto the Mono that it is returning so it never gets subscribed to because it is not in the event chain.

```
return request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class)
    .map( demoPOJO -> {
        return demoClient.add(demoPOJO);
    });
```

If you change it to `map` it will probably work. What is happening then is that it is taking a `Mono<DemoPojo>` and "mapping" it to a `Mono<Void>` that is returned by your `add` function. And suddenly it is in the event chain (callback).

Comment: The actual solution used *flatmap* (see revised question), but I have finally recognized that my error is in not paying enough attention to the signatures of the functional interfaces for the lambdas. I will need to do this a bit more, I believe, to really feel like I'm getting the idea of how to do reactive chains and lambdas, but...getting there. Thanks for your patience.